# How to test generated html using jest without snapshot

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

I am trying to test some dynamically created html.
Currently, I have to create a snapshot and match the generated block and the expected block to the snapshot.

What I would like to do is just compare the expected and generated blocks without a snapshot, likey so:

```
test('should create div elements', () => {
  const expectedElements = <div><div key={1}>test</div></div>;
  const generatedElements = [<div key={1}>test</div>];
  const op = <div>{generatedElements}</div>;
  expect(op).toEqual(expectedElements);
});
```

This fails with the following message:

```
Compared values have no visual difference.

  at Object.<anonymous>.test (src/App.test.js:8:14)
      at new Promise (<anonymous>)
  at Promise.resolve.then.el (node_modules/p-map/index.js:46:16)
      at <anonymous>
  at process._tickCallback
  at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)_
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like enzyme to test that.

Shallow

> Shallow rendering is useful to constrain yourself to testing a component as a unit, and to ensure that your tests aren't indirectly asserting on behavior of child components.
>   http://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/shallow.html

Or Mount for full rendering:

> Full DOM rendering is ideal for use cases where you have components that may interact with DOM APIs, or may require the full lifecycle in order to fully test the component (i.e., componentDidMount etc.)
>   http://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/mount.html

I prefer to use shallow, because I can test if the component exists or not. In the inside component, I normally use mount, to see if my tags are there and working fine.

Comment: thanx for the response but I am currently rendering (using jest test renderer) and matching against snapshot, I thought I made that clear in OP so apologies if not. What I am trying to achieve is the expect comparison shown, but not sure what I'm doing wrong to get the error shown.